# Rails 4: Allow field to be null on create but not null on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build an application where I would like one group of users to create an object and other users can update it after it has been created. This model has attributes that cannot have data entered during the create method, but these attributes should not be null on update. I have searched but cannot seem to find anything on this. I suspect that it is not possible....hope I'm wrong. Thanks in advance for any help or guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for a conditional validation:

```
validates :your_field, presence: true, unless: :new_record?
```

or, there is an [**`on`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) option that lets you specify when the validation should happen:

```
validates :your_field, presence: true, on: :update
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This is great...I should have known rails would have this problem solved